# File Explorer Crashing on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10

Whenever i tried to open the file manager it crashes right away but if i go to my Documents for example , i can acess all my files via the dropdown menu like nothing was wrong.

I tried also to right click some folders like c/program files/windowsapp and whenever i right click this folder it crashes too (probably because its a hidden folder and protected[but i got away anyway avoiding to right click and stuff])
Anyone know to fix , i can easily reproduce this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the `utx.dll` from Autodesk Inventor 2014 cause the crash:

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffd0713a1c8 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000068)
   ExceptionCode: e06d7363 (C++ EH exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 4
   Parameter[0]: 0000000019930520
   Parameter[1]: 000000000216abc0
   Parameter[2]: 00007ffcdf76db30
   Parameter[3]: 00007ffcdf600000

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe06d7363 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe06d7363 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000019930520

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000000216abc0

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  00007ffcdf76db30

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER4: 7ffcdf600000

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  explorer.exe

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000738814f1 to 00007ffd0713a1c8

STACK_TEXT:  
00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 ntdll!RtlReportExceptionEx
02 ntdll!RtlReportException
03 ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode$filt$1
04 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
05 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
06 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
07 ntdll!RtlRaiseException
08 KERNELBASE!RaiseException
09 msvcr100!CxxThrowException
0a utx
0b utx
0c 0x0
0d utx


FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  utx.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_e06d7363_utx.dll!Unknown

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:application_fault_e06d7363_utx.dll!unknown

    Loaded symbol image file: utx.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Inventor 2014\Bin\utx.dll
    Image name: utx.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Thu Feb 28 22:59:45 2013
```

Install [the latest update and look if this fixes it](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-products/downloads/caas/downloads/content/update-6-for-inventor-2014-service-pack-2.html).

Comment: Thanks dude ur smart. Invetor 2014 is not compatible with Windows 10, unnistaled and now everything works fine. :D

Comment: Btw how do i read my dump file as you did?

Comment: I used Windbg.exe (**!analyze -v**) from the Windows SDK/Debugger.

Comment: hey I tried that but i dont get the same info. i get some symbols error idk
do i need anything else installed? http://1drv.ms/1P7yKYP

Comment: you get the same like I did. For the stack command I used **kc** to remove the parameters.

Comment: I was just wondering because mine doenst show the path of the file like yours but i can see the error dll so i guess thats fine anyway

Comment: type **lmvm utx**

Comment: Thanks! i never used this software , great to learn about this THAAANKS!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! I had the same problem with Autodesk Inventor 2013.

Answer (score 6):

Just as an update to the next person coming across this page, I had the exact same problem after KB3081449. Getting rid of it fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks, uninstalled KB3081449 and now right click is working again!

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to delete two updates: KB3081449 (as suggested [in Burak's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/950659/file-explorer-crashing-on-windows-10/968647#968647)) and KB3081448.

To delete this, follow:

- Settings > Windows Update > Advanced Options > View Your Update History > Uninstall Updates.
- Choose update, uninstall, restart.

Answer (score 4):

Found this solution in a youtube comment, this worked for me.

> Problems started yesterday when I changed the display size from the
>   default setting (150%) to the maximum (175%). You mentioned reverting
>   back to 150%, and bang! problem fixed!

Comment: Holy crap. This works... Insane.

Comment: Yeah, thought the same, a combination of your comments, Fu**ing holy crazy crap.

Comment: Seriously - could this be a fix? One of my clients has this problem so I rebuilt her PC. Same problem. But the first thing she did was change the display size... currently we've turned recent items off!

Answer (score 0):

Explorer crash with right click on everything:
To fix it, open Explorer and for every disk partion, select properties (from the ribbon so not crashing) and in security give full control for the user account. Apply and click ok. The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to find the cause of explorer crashing, your best bet is to use WinDbg using the steps that Andrew has written [here](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/49515).