# Windows 10 Explorer Crash

Tags: windows, upgrade

I updated my Windows 7 Home to Windows 10 Home and now as soon as my PC starts the explorer keeps crashing and won't let me do anything....I found out that MS already have released a fix as Update which is available as https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3020114

Can someone help me how to install this as I tried somehow running Windows Update but it says my PC is up to date!

Comment: That update was for the Technical Preview. Does anything [here](http://superuser.com/questions/954869/windows-10-file-explorer-crashes) or [here](http://superuser.com/questions/950659/file-explorer-crashing-on-windows-10) help your case?

Comment: capture a crash dump and share it: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: Crash dump can be downloaded from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xajk1sif9ysatv/explorer.exe.4052.zip?dl=0

Comment: If above link does not work use this https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ij19plv6g7lobsx/AABULUMAzs1HzdMj5tBDpE5Qa?dl=0 for crash dump

Comment: I gave up and yelled back to my working Windows 7 Home

Answer (score 1):

Start Windows 10 in safe mode with networking by following these steps:

1. Start > Settings > Update & Security > Recovery
2. Go to Advanced start-up and select Restart now
3. Once rebooted, select option screen > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Start-up Settings > Restart
4. Once the device has restarted, select safe mode with networking by pressing the corresponding number
5. Conduct Windows Update (Start > Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update)

Comment: Windows update runs forever! Never returns back... :(